# How to identify SQS queue that fed DLQ SQS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have various SQS queues, connected with one single DLQ queue, and a Lambda function started by DLQ. Is the a way to identify the original queue that fed the DLQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you have some sort of source queue identifier included in the message body.